# Self-referencing generics and getting your own instance back

Tags: java, generics

I have a *location* and a *processor* which processes a location. Given a location, the client can request a processor for that location. I implemented `Location` as following:

```
public abstract class Location<SELF extends Location<SELF>> {
    ...

    public Processor<SELF> processor() {
        return new Processor(this);
    }
}
```

I am creating and using subclasses from `Location`, never `Location` directly:

```
public class SecretLocation extends Location<SecretLocation> {
   ...
}
```

I need type-safety on the processor, so only references belonging to this concrete secret location class instance can be provided (omitted here), hence the usage of `SELF` and subclasses, and providing a typed `Location` to the processor.

Now, I wanted to implemented `Processor` as following:

```
public class Processor<L extends Location<L>> {
    private final L location;

    public Processor(L location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public L location() {
        return location;
    }

    ...
}
```

But with this implementation, `new Processor(this)` in `Location` is invalid. I found two ways to solve this, but I am not certain which is best:

- Do `new Processor(this)` instead of `new Processor<>(this)` in `Location`, so basically disabling generics.
- Accept `Location<L>` instead of `L` in the constructor and member variable in `Processor`. The consequence is that the getter `location` in `Processor` now must return `Location<L>` instead of `L` as above. The downside is that `processor.location()` now never will return a `SecretLocation` anymore, when creating a processor on `SecretLocation`, but a `Location<SecretLocation>`. This is kinda sloppy, because now I can never get a `SecretLocation` back via the processor.

For reference, this is my second solution:

```
public class Processor<L extends Location<L>> {
    private final Location<L> location;

    public Processor(Location<L> location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Location<L> location() {
        return location;
    }

    ...
}
```

Is there anything better to to?

Comment: If you want more people to understand your code quickly, stick to Java conventions.  Use a single uppercase letter for a generic type.  Do not name a generic argument to make it look like a class name (which is what `LocationType` is doing).

Comment: OK, I updated my question.

Comment: I would suggest an OO design where `Location` encapsulates its own processing logic and objects do not expose their internal state. The current design is very procedural, i.e. the opposite of OO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the most straight-forward solution is probably like this:

```
public abstract class Location<SELF extends Location<SELF>> {
    ...

    public Processor<SELF> processor() {
        return new Processor<>( self() );
    }

    protected abstract SELF self();
}

public class SecretLocation extends Location<SecretLocation> {
    ...

    @Override
    protected SecretLocation self() { return this; }
}
```

The issue is that the given bound doesn't actually restrict the type argument to being the type of `this`, for example the following class would compile:

```
class BadLocation extends Location<SecretLocation> {}
```

The other solution is to use an unchecked cast:

```
return new Processor<>((SELF) this);
```

That will also work, but as shown by `BadLocation`, there's no real restriction that `this` is actually an object of `SELF`. (However, for the `abstract` method solution, there's no restriction that the subclass has to return `this` from the method, so neither solution is perfect when it comes to guaranteeing correctness.)